# Uploading 1 java file to emulator (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, emulation, android-studio

Every time I make a change to 1 java file in android studio - I hit run - then it seems like the emulator is rendering the entire project before it runs the app. This usally takes between 1 - 2 minutes.

If I were to only change 1 file, is there a way to update the app with just the 1 file? Instead of reloading the entire project.

I just hate having to wait 1 -2 minutes everytime I want to run....

Comment: if this is not possible what are some tips to make emulator run faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is possible. All the resources are wrapped in an apk file and then .apk file is installed by the package manager service in android OS.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but do u have any tips that will make emilator run faster?

Comment: Again sorry. I dont think you can. All you can do is dont shut down you AVD so it will be a little faster as it does not has to go through the boot process. and PS it is a good practice to accept answers if you agree.